# Theories of manifolds w/ extra structure and singularities

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, big-list, singularity-theory

Many different objects in mathematics can be described as manifolds with extra structure. Among the most famous examples of these are smooth manifolds, Riemannian manifolds, complex manifolds, and symplectic manifolds. There have been efforts to unify these examples by defining a general notion of what an extra structure to be placed on manifolds is. For this question I am happy to use these or a prerigorous notion.

Sometimes in mathematics that are "mostly" manifolds with extra structure, but allow some singularities where the space is not a manifold (or, the space may be technically isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ at these points, but not in a way "compatible" with this extra structure). To be (partially) precise, we have a category of spaces where some subcategory is a category of manifolds with extra structure,  and every space contains a dense open subspace isomorphic to an object in that category, but not every space is itself isomorphic to an object in that category.

My questions are whether there are examples of such categories of spaces which have been fruitful in mathematics other than those I list below, and whether there exist unexpected questions between different such categories.

Of course there are many examples of functions or other objects on spaces which become singular at certain points, but I'm interested only in settings where spaces themselves become singular.

---

The most famous example here is probably the category of reduced complex analytic spaces, spaces locally isomorphic to the vanishing loci of analytic functions in $\mathbb C^n$. Each of these has an open subset that is a complex analytic manifold but may not be a complex analytic manifold itself. Complex algebraic varieties are a subcategory of these. There is a vast zoo of different conditions we can place on the singularities of such a space, defining subcategories which are often of interest.

Presumably the ur-example is the category of topological spaces with a finite stratification all whose strata are manifolds. The theory of intersection cohomology of Goresky and Macpherson is applicable in this level of generality, though most of the motivating examples come from complex analytic spaces.

The example that inspired this question is in differential geometry, specifically the theory of the Ricci flow. Ricci flow on a three-manifold $M$ is a differential equation that varies the metric. A solution to Ricci flow is therefore a kind of geometric structure on the four-manifold $M \times [0,\infty)$. Ricci flow does not always exist for all time due to singularities appearing. Perelman's work uses surgery to remove these singularities, but this requires non-canonical choices. A canonical version is provided by considering Ricci flow with singularities as a certain limit of Perelman's construction. This is worked out in papers of Bamler, Kleiner, and Lott and involves a generalization of these four-manifolds with geoemtric structure where certain singularities are allowed.

Finally, in differential geometry, there are minimal hypersurfaces in Riemannian manifolds one dimension higher, which can be allowed to admit certain singularities. Interestingly, in this setting, singularities only appear in large dimension: for hypersurfaces of dimension $\geq 7$ in manifolds of dimension $\geq 8$.

Comment: I am surprised you didn't mention orbifolds, but maybe I misunderstood the point of the question. (By the way, I think you are missing a couple words in the sentence that begins 'Sometimes in mathematics that are "mostly" manifolds ...')

Comment: Orbifolds and cone manifolds.

Comment: I think there are words missing at the beginning of the second paragraph ("Sometimes in mathematics that are 'mostly' manifolds with extra structure").

Comment: The category of spaces which are framed manifolds away from a single point arises both when studying Koszul duality of $E_n$-algebras (https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.2478) and when studying Goodwillie derivatives of functors $\mathrm{Top}_* \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}$ (https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.1809).

Comment: Etale groupoids generalize orbifolds. Lott used these in taking limits of Ricci flow. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00208-007-0127-x

Comment: Some other notions that come to mind: David Spivak’s thesis defined derived manifolds. https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=2641940 Perelman studied Alexandrov spaces of curvature bounded below and finite dimension and proved that these are stratified (so maybe these fall under the stratified category). https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=1220498 Kreck defined a theory of stratifolds http://www.journalofsing.org/volume18/article14.html

Comment: @SamHopkins As an algebraic geometer I don't think of orbifolds as singular at all! But of course they fit the definition I gave.

Comment: Spaces obtained by singular symplectic reduction have a top stratum that is a symplectic manifold and thus would fit your description I guess. Other examples from the symplectic world are log or $b^m$-symplectic structures.

Comment: It isn't fully clear to me how Ricci flow and minimal surfaces fit into the categorical setup you suggested, but there are many quite similar examples from differential geometry and PDE, such as Cheeger-Colding theory, mean curvature flow with surgery, harmonic maps, singular Kahler-Einstein metrics and conic singularities, singular Yamabe metrics, etc. I'm not sure how to judge the difference between singular space and singular object (eg the canonical singular minimal surface, the Simons cone, could be viewed as a smooth object on a smooth space), so maybe these aren't what you have in mind.